# How to allow all browser redirects when running in TestCafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcafe

My application has a payment card section inside of an iFrame. When running tests via TestCafe once the payment card form is submitted the form just gets stuck in 'processing' mode. As I'm trying to debug this issue I see that Chrome is blocking a redirect URL. I've tried to change my Chrome settings to allow all pop-ups but this is not adhered to when running via TestCafe.

So how can I set TestCafe browser to allow all pop-up? Is there a parameter I can pass when starting the test?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Could you send us a simple example of the page that shows the "Redirect blocked" warning when it's opened by TestCafe? This might be helpful for our further research.

As temporary workaround you can consider usage of [User Profiles](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/browsers.html#user-profiles).

Comment: Sure, I will look for a public site to reproduce the issue and email example to TestCafe support.

Comment: I've emailed a live env example to support@devexpress.com